# Interchanging limits with a special kind of series.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\{a_{ij}\}_{(i,j)\in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb N}$ is a doubly-indexed sequence of real numbers and $\{\alpha_j\}_{j \in \mathbb N}$ is a sequence of real numbers such that:

1) For each $i$, $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij} = 1$.

2) For each $j$, $\lim_{i\to \infty} a_{ij} = \alpha_j$.

**Prove or disprove: $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \alpha_j = 1$.**

Maybe there are more assumptions to add here. I'm open to anything.  I was thinking that one assumption is to add that $\sum \alpha_j$ converges, or maybe that it's bounded by 1, or that we are dealing only with nonnegative real numbers? Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $a_{nj} = \frac{1}{n}$ for $1\leq j \leq n$ and $a_{nj} = 0$ otherwise.  What are $\alpha_j$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^\infty \alpha_j$ in this case?

Additional comments:

One can show that if that $a_{ij}$ are nonnegative, then $\displaystyle 0\leq  \sum_{j=1}^\infty \alpha_j \leq 1$.  If in addition we assume there is a function $f(n)$ with $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(n) = 1$ such that for all $i$, the partial sums satisfy $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} \geq f(n)$, then $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j \geq f(n)$ as well and hence $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^\infty \alpha_j = 1$.

Comment: $\alpha_j = 0$, so their sum is 0.  Okay so now what? What are some additional hypotheses I can add to make this true?

Comment: I've added my responses to the answer.

Comment: That's nice. It's like an asymptotic condition on the $a_{ij}$... somewhat similar to a probability distribution in that way.